# Erro em EmbeddedId

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Tenho a chave composta abaixo, o problema é que na hora de criar o `schema` e salvar os valores, o Hibernate está invertendo os valores de `TipoContrato` com `Distribuidora` e vice-versa. Alguém já teve alguma anomalia semelhante utilizando o `embeddedid`?

```
@Embeddable
public class IdentificadorUnidadeConsumidoraId implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -8961508936592415161L;

/*
 * Além do idUnidade herdado, este identificador é informado pela
 * Distribuidora, único, mas não pode ser alterado.
 */
@Index(name = "IDX_IDENTUNIDADECONSUMIDORA_CODUNIDADECONSUMIDORA", columnNames = "CODUNIDADECONSUMIDORA")
@Column(name = "CODUNIDADECONSUMIDORA", length = 20, nullable = false)
private String codUnidadeConsumidora;

@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
@Column(name = "TIPOCONTRATO", length = 20)
private TipoContrato tipoContrato;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "IDDISTRIBUIDORA")
private Distribuidora distribuidora;
```

Comment: Quando você vai nas colunas do banco, os valores estão invertidos nas colunas `TIPOCONTRATO` e `IDDISTRIBUIDORA` ?

Comment: exatamente,por ex se configuro o enum TipoContrato  para String, o IDDISTRIBUIDORA recebe o valor string do enum TipoContrato. a criação do schema e a inserção estão trocados.

Answer (score 1):

```
Problema resolvido,
```

a ordem do joinColumns estava interferindo na inserção e criação das colunas como FK

**Invertendo:**
public abstract class Contrato{

```
@OneToOne
    @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "CODUNIDADECONSUMIDORA"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "TIPOCONTRATO"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "IDDISTRIBUIDORA") })
    private IdentificadorUnidadeConsumidora identificador;


}
```

PARA:

```
public abstract class Contrato{

@OneToOne
    @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "CODUNIDADECONSUMIDORA"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "IDDISTRIBUIDORA"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "TIPOCONTRATO"),})
    private IdentificadorUnidadeConsumidora identificador;
}
```

alguem sabe o por que desta ordem interferir? faz algum sentido?